# Why am I getting an additional category when I try to group them?

Tags: r

I am trying to group some the workclass categories in the Adult income dataset based on the existing values using gsub. However, I end up getting two versions of the "Other-Unknown" category. Can someone help me understand why? The nas/nulls have ? in the fields. Thank you in advance!

Below is my code

```
total_data <- read.csv("adult_data_set.csv")

levels(total_data$workclass)[1] <- "Unknown"
total_data$workclass <- gsub("Federal-gov", "Public Sector",total_data$workclass)
total_data$workclass <- gsub("Local-gov", "Public Sector", total_data$workclass)
total_data$workclass <- gsub("State-gov", "Public Sector", total_data$workclass)
total_data$workclass <- gsub("Self-emp-inc", "Self Employed", total_data$workclass)
total_data$workclass <- gsub("Self-emp-not-inc", "Self Employed", total_data$workclass) 
total_data$workclass <- gsub("Never-worked", "Other-Unknown", total_data$workclass) #this is part of the 17 count
total_data$workclass <- gsub("Without-pay", "Other-Unknown", total_data$workclass) #this is part of the 17 count
total_data$workclass <- gsub("^Unknown", "Other-Unknown", total_data$workclass)

total_data$workclass <- as.factor(total_data$workclass)
```

This is the result I'm getting

```
 Other-Unknown        Private  Public Sector  Self Employed  Other-Unknown 
            17          22333           4335           3716           1859
```

I'm expecting

```
 Other-Unknown        Private  Public Sector  Self Employed   
            1876          22333           4335           3716
```

Comment: Are there spaces included after the first Other-Unknown

Comment: No, there aren't. There is no value of "Other-Unknown" in the original dataset. All instances were because of the gsub code.

Comment: Looks like the accepted answer points to my suspicion/comment being correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears that in your CSV file, the fields are separated by a comma and a space.

So your Other-Unknown levels were not all the same, some were `Other-Unknown` while others were `whitespaceOther-Unknown`.

In this case you can add the `strip.white=TRUE` option to the `read.csv` command, this will remove the whitespaces at the beginning and at the end of your fields.

Answer (score 0):

See if the code below does what you want. It uses package `forcats` function `fct_collapse` to collapse the factor levels.
This is **untested** since there is no example dataset in the question.

```
library(forcats)

all_workclass <- levels(total_data$workclass)
public <- c("Federal-gov", "Local-gov", "State-gov")
selfemp <- c("Self-emp-inc", "Self-emp-not-inc")
other <- setdiff(all_workclass, c(public, selfemp))

total_data$workclass <- fct_collapse(total_data$workclass,
  'Public Sector' = public,
  'Self Employed' = selfemp,
  'Other-Unknown' = other
)
```

Comment: I tried this and received an error "Error in check_factor(.f) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default"

Comment: @AMorell In the first version I had forgotten the first argument, the factor to be changed `total_data$workclass`.  Try it now to see if it works.